# iOS 13 UIViewController doesn't state restore its modalPresentationStyle to fullscreen

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios13, state-restoration

I've adopted the new iOS 13 modal presentation style across most of the modals in my app, however one navigation controller doesn't really fit the new style well so I set it to

`UIModalPresentationFullScreen`

when presenting it which works fine.

I just noticed a bug that when my app undergoes state preservation and restoration whilst on a ViewController being presented modally its loaded back in after restoration with a modalPresentationStyle of UIModalPresentationPageSheet.

As built in properties of a ViewController their state restoration is Apple's responsibility and I guess they just missed out handling it properly.

Thankfully I've been able to fix the issue by adding the following to my existing state restoration handling

```
- (void)decodeRestorableStateWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
  ...
  self.navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen; 
}
```

Anyone else encountered this or got an alternative solution?

Cheers

Comment: Also experiencing this problem and your fix works.  Have yet to find something more elegant...  Seem to be getting a new warning: `Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UINavigationController: ...>.` Thinking this is causing it

Comment: @james - nice spot. Here’s hoping they fix it eventually. I’d log a bug with Apple about it but it takes more time than I’ve got to do and I’m sure they’re aware of it. Glad this fix worked for you.